# Identifying connect to Postgres using node pg-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have an application using a PostgreSQL database with multiple backend-API's. Because we some times run out of connections, I would like to be able to identify which backend API has active connections in view pg_stat_activity. Is it possible to identify the connection from node pg-postgres?

Answer (score 0):

What you see (in pg_stat_activity) is what you get.  If none of those fields are helpful, then I guess the answer is no.

Aren't all the APIs pooled together through the same shared connections?

Application_name could help if you can convince node.js to set them per API.  query text could help if you recognize what query text is from which API.